# Is there any way to parse .mpd file and download all the media from url generated?

Tags: javascript, streaming, mpeg, dash.js

I'm using mpd-parser to parse the ".mpd" file and generate URLs so I've got a few questions:-

1. How many types of configurations I can find in the file or is there any better way to generate URLs ?
2. Can I download the media in playable format or do I need anything else for that?